# How to delete the entire document in mongodb nodejs using the ObjectId?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have the objectID as `idd=60041d4312e61330c4b93b9b` i've tried using

```
db.collection('users').remove({"_id":"ObjectId("+idd+")" })
```

but this isn't working.

Comment: Deleting a document from mongodb works, except in this case? What is different about this case?

Comment: Or does this code just not work at all, for any record?

Comment: @RobertHarvey doesn't work for any record

Comment: remove double quotes from "ObjectId()", it should be just `_id: ObjectId(idd)`

Comment: Well, then you're not using the right code.  Determine what technology you are using that corresponds to the `remove` method, read it, and follow its instructions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey was able to run this query  db.users.remove({"_id":ObjectId("60041d4312e61330c4b93b9b")})
WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 1 }) but i'm not able to achieve this in code

Comment: @turivishal has a point.  Why would you put idd in quotes?

Comment: ok i'll give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

db.collection('users', function(err, collection) {
   collection.deleteOne({_id: new mongodb.ObjectID(idd)});
});
```